# Add and load images, videos and pdfs from a raw folder or an SDCard Android Tablet design?

Tags: android

Good day, I have a requirement to create a kind of book app with pdfs, images and videos worth up to 10gb and more on a tablet locally. Now there is no intention to sell it on the android market or any other store, its completely in house, so i think issue with apk size has been clarified. What am asking is, where is the best place to put all this contents so that i can readily load them up and use them accordingly?

1. Should i be using the raw folder and create sub-folders for each images, videos and pdfs?
2. Should i create folders on an sdcard(assuming there is one in place)? or

Please if you have any other solution or ideas on how to implement this, I would gladly like to hear this. Thanks for your responses in advance.

P.S by the way, since its a tablet specific app, is there any need to have a multi-pane layout fragment or ii can just use all the space. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can use a RAW folder, but it would also make the APK size huge from what I understand because all the files in the RAW folder need to be packaged with the application.

From what I've seen in the past, most applications, actually most games, that have lots of extra data will download the additional data on first launch. Basically:

1. The application launches
2. It checks whether or not you have all the additional data (Books, pdfs, images)
3. If not, it starts downloading that data to the SDCARD.

It may not make sense in your situation, but doing it this way gives you more finite control over how much data *needs* to be downloaded. If function A only requires package A of additional data, then you only need to download package A, you don't need to download *everything*. Or perhaps you could let the user choose what packages of additional data they want to download, which would also save bandwidth, time and resources.

Comment: thanks for the response, that would have been ideal, i Know it would make the apk file huge, but in this case everything has to be local, no need to have a data connection at all.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that there may be limitations I just don't know about. It's unfortunate, becuase the whole *giant apk* idea also means that minor updates to your application will require the user to download tons of unaffected content all over again.

Comment: i think its just once. yeah with the issues of minor updates in case of bug fixes, do you think i should creating folders manually in the sdcard and storing the contents there will be a better idea before i start coding the app instead of having it in a raw folder? I think the whole idea is that everything will be pre-installed in the device, so no update will be required by the users part. As i say, its all in-house. its a strange one i know. :)

Comment: Well, you say *manually*, so does that mean the application will be small and you'll manually install all the additional content on the SDCARD? That could work if you are *sure* you'll never need to update the content. As for efficiency of reading data from RAW folder vs SDCARD, I have no idea, but I would **guess** reading from RAW would be faster.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks for the feedback once again.